# I want to release a C dynamic library for linux. At run time, will it be compatible with any linux version?

Tags: c++, c, linux, dynamic-library

My little open-source C/C++ project also offers precompiled dynamic libraries to allow other languages to bind. For Windows I just provide x86 and x64 versions. For Macos, I propose an intel x64 version and a M1/M2 version.

For Linux, I have x86 and x64 versions, but I wonder if these are compatible with any Linux version, or only with the Linux 6.2 used to produce them.

```
gcc -m64 -fPIC -shared -o tinyfiledialogsLinux64.so ../tinyfiledialogs.c
```

ldd tinyfiledialogsLinux64.so

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdd87b3000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8afcc00000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8afd006000)
```

objdump -T tinyfiledialogsLinux64.so | grep GLIBC_

```
maximum is GLIBC_2.7
```

Comment: The kernel does changes that break userspace rarely (although not never). The main breakage will come from library dependencies like libc. What does `ldd ./tinyfiledialogsLinux64.so` say?

Comment: I would just tell users to build themselves. The only reason to provide prebuilt libraries is to hide the code.

Comment: If you don't link to any libraries explicitly then libc will be the major compatibility restriction. The minimum version of that mostly dictates which Linux distributions it can run on (as you can't really upgrade libc in-place without a distribution upgrade). Note that some Linux distributions like Alpine don't ship with glibc (the "default") at all and use their own. Those will most likely not be compatible out of the box.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat bindings are for people who don't use C and don't even have a C compiler.

Comment: If you want to find out the minimum version of glibc that your built library needs, try also `objdump -T` (and look for the max GLIBC_something dependency). And if you want to lower that, build on some older distro.

Comment: If you really care about compatibility across various Linux distros, you should build with the oldest libc you can find (eg using a `centos:6` docker image).

Comment: Then there is also the dependency of the versions of other libraries your library relies on. You have `tinyfiledialogsLinux64.so` and, perhaps wrong, but that would appear to be file-open, file-save, file-saveas, etc.. dialogs that usually rely on some GUI toolkit, Qt, Gtk, fltk, wxwidgets, etc.. If you simply provide the library and the end user doesn't have a version-compatible install of the toolkit your library relies on -- more problems occur. I'd 2nd just providing the code and letting the end user build it.

Comment: `maximum is GLIBC_2.7` What output is this? I do not think `objdump -T` outputs "maximum is GLIBC_2.7". Don't you see like `<hex> DF UND <hex> (GLIBC_..) symbol_name` formatted output?

Answer (score 0):

Since the library is [open source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyfiledialogs/), there is no need nor any advantage at *releasing* a binary version of the library for linux.  You should instead provide the source code along with a simple `Makefile` to produce the library or the object file for the user's target system.

You can also just document the compilation command:

```
gcc -m64 -fPIC -shared -o libtinyfiledialogs.so tinyfiledialogs.c
```

Answer (score 0):

> At run time, will it be compatible with **any** linux version?

No. You compiled your library against glibc. It will not be able to run out of the box on Linux without glibc, in particular on alpine Linux which uses musl.

> with any Linux version,

Linux does not really have a "version". Linux is created from millions of components, and almost every single one of them has a different version. Linux kernel version is not so much relevant, as the kernel has a very strict API policy that it very rarely changes.

> maximum is GLIBC_2.7

Glibc 2.7 is from 2007, so most probably you should be fine nowadays. I think linking against glibc 2.7 is more than fine and should work on any nowadays used glibc based Linux distribution.

> objdump -T tinyfiledialogsLinux64.so | grep GLIBC_

This output looks nice:

```
objdump -T ....so | grep -o 'GLIBC_[0-9\.]*.*' | sort -u -V -t.
```